# How often should the red fibre body washer be replaced in a tap?

Tags: plumbing, taps, washer

Should the red fibre body washer be replaced as well when you disassemble a tap to replace the tape valve and "O" ring as a convenient mean to update all the wearable parts or do they last much longer (someone indicated to me that they could last for decades) and I should only replace them when there is a need to do so?

Comment: Mobile app idea: Red fiber washer replacement reminder calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever they leak. If it's loose & just pops out there's no harm in replacing it, assuming you have a replacement. If it's solid & seems possibly part of a cartridge then leave it until the cartridge needs replacing...they either don't turn off completely or they turn off before you hit the stop.